# 2 types of telomerases?

Tags: dna, rna, enzymes, telomere, protein-binding

As telomerase works by adding new nucleotides complementary to the RNA it contains, it cannot work for the complementary strand.

Say telomerase X has RNA complementary to the 5' to 3' strand it cannot elongate he telomere for the 3'to 5' strand.

So does a cell have 2 types of telomerases ? One for 5' to 3' and another for 3' to 5' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A second telomerase is not necessary, as the lagging strand is filled in by the DNA-Polymerase, see this [figure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telomerase):

[image]